# How to compile and run a java file that contain weka libraries in dos?

Tags: java, compilation, weka

I am not much familiar with java but i know the usual method we are compile a java file is

```
path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin
javac main.java
java main
```

But when  i try that weka libraries do not working. I am using jre 1.7 with weka for my program . Please anyone enlighten me how to include the weka libraries and compile the java code.

Comment: you have to add your jars to classpath. javac -cp "jars" main.java

Answer (score 1):

You need to know two things .

1. how to add a directory to a class path .
2. where your weka.jar and/or weka-src.jar files are

Now ,

STEP 1. COMPILE THE CODE

To compile the code you need to give the following command .

`javac -classpath "path/to/lib1:path/to/lib2" main.java`

This line tells javac to compile 'main.java' and use the libraries if it needs to .

STEP 2.RUN THE CODE

To run the code you just need to the same thing as above but along with the `path/to/libs` you should also add the `path/to/yourpresentdirectory/` just to be on the safe side as there might be some extra .class files generated after compilation that JVM need to use .

`java -classpath "path/to/lib1.jar:path/to/lib2.jar:path/to/yourpresentdirectory/" main`

This should do the trick.

PS: I have given the commands for linux (i am using ubuntu 14.04). They should work just fine on Windows with slight changes ( you need to use '\'instead of '/' and use ';' instead of ':' where you separate the paths).